# <Class TypeError> MetaWear accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not a great programmer at all and have a very basic knowledge. I have a MetaWear accel and gyro and I'm just trying to stream both accelerometer and gyro data from the sensor via bluetooth. Here's the code that I have:

```
import time
from mbientlab.metawear import MetaWear, libmetawear
from mbientlab.metawear.cbindings import *
from mbientlab.warble import *
from mbientlab.metawear import *
from threading import Event
from time import sleep
import ctypes

# Define the data handler method
def data_handler(data):
    print("Accelerometer data: x = {0:.3f}, y = {1:.3f}, z = {2:.3f}".format(data['accelerometer'][0], data['accelerometer'][1], data['accelerometer'][2]))
    print("Gyro data: x = {0:.3f}, y = {1:.3f}, z = {2:.3f}".format(data['gyro'][0], data['gyro'][1], data['gyro'][2]))

# Create a state object to store information about the device and the number of data samples received
class State:
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device
        self.samples = 0

# Connect to the device using its MAC address
device = MetaWear("ADDRESS")
device.connect()

# Set the connection parameters
libmetawear.mbl_mw_settings_set_connection_parameters(device.board, 7.5, 7.5, 0, 6000)

# Configure the accelerometer
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_set_odr(device.board, 100)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_set_range(device.board, 8.0)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_write_acceleration_config(device.board)

# Configure the gyro
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_set_odr(device.board, 100)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_set_range(device.board, 2000)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_write_config(device.board)

# Create a state object and subscribe to the accelerometer and gyro data streams
state = State(device)
accelerometer = libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_get_acceleration_data_signal(device.board)
gyro = libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_get_rotation_data_signal(device.board)

cb_fun = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(Data))(data_handler) # NOT WORKING
libmetawear.mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(accelerometer, None, cb_fun) # NOT WORKING
libmetawear.mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(gyro, None, cb_fun) # NOT WORKING

# Start streaming dat
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_enable_acceleration_sampling(device.board)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_enable_rotation_sampling(device.board)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_start(device.board)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_start(device.board)

#Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5.0)

#Stop the accelerometer and gyro
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_stop(device.board)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_stop(device.board)

#Disable acceleration and rotation sampling
libmetawear.mbl_mw_acc_disable_acceleration_sampling(device.board)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_gyro_bmi160_disable_rotation_sampling(device.board)

#Disconnect from the device
device.disconnect()
```

I really appreciate it if someone can help me get this issue resolved.

I have tried changing the code from:

```
libmetawear.mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(accelerometer, None, data_handler)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(gyro, None, data_handler)
```

to the following without really understanding the details:

```
cb_fun = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(Data))(data_handler)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(accelerometer, None, cb_fun)
libmetawear.mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(gyro, None, cb_fun)
```

but its still not working and I'm very lost at what the issue is or the solution.

Answer (score 0):

in MetaWear Python API 1.0.2,

we have :

```
def data_handler(self, ctx, data):
    print("%s -> %s" % (device.address, parse_value(data)))
```

So I think you should modify your callback `def data_handler(data)` to `def data_handler(context, data)`